# Invalid template file: 'RewardPointsBehavior::scripts.phtml' on login page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, login

I am not able to access the `customer login page` (Blank white screen while accessing)suddenly, But i can access to `sign-up page` & other pages too. No errors in console.

[image: please refer this screenshot]

But I see this below error in log file:

> main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file:
>   'RewardPointsBehavior::scripts.phtml' in module:
>   'Lof_RewardPointsBehavior' block's name: 'lrw.fb.scripts' [] []

I'm not sure that this error causing problem or not.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: disable the module from `app/etc/config.php` and try to run admin url to debug if the same extension is causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your Rewards module is broken, as the error says. Investigate the module or disable it.

Answer (score 0):

**If you used the Magento 2 Reward Points Plus extension from Magestore, which is what this issue sounds like, try this:**

1. Uninstall the `Reward Points Plus` extension
2. Generate your license certificate for the Magestore extension again and reinstall the package.
3. `cd [magento 2 root folder]` and `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
   *Wait a sec to complete the reinstall*
4. If your website is in the `Default` or the `Production` mode, type this at the command line from your Magento root folder: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
5. In the Magento 2 admin, confirm the extension is installed properly. Should show up in your `menu bar` or in the Configuration in the backend.

**Note:** *If those steps don't work, your version of Magento may not be compatible with the extension. Otherwise, more detailed system info and module info are probably be needed to recreate/debug here.*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion guy's, I solved the issue by flushing the cache. I don't know what is the exact problem, But after i flushed the cache the issue resolved. this is the command i tried & it worked, Thanks

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```